# Does AWS Internet Gateway Id always start with "igw-" or it may be different?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Does AWS Internet Gateway Id always start with "igw-" or it may be different ?

Similarly I want to know about the Nat Gateway Id and VPC Endpoint Id.

Comment: Why is the prefix significant to you? There's no documented guarantee what these prefixes will be afaik. Practically speaking, they likely won't change but that's not authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

Resource IDs will have a specific naming format for the ID, this will generally stay the same through the entire lifecycle of the product itself.

There are occasions where the format might change, an example of this is when EC2 instances had their suffix lengthened to increase availability. These kinds of changes are communicated months in advance with the choice of opting in early.

Comment: So "igw--xxxxxxxx" will always be a Internet gateway because the Id is starting with "igw" until the format gets changed ?

Comment: Means, I want to know for a resource can resource identifier change ? Eg for Internet Gateway "igw" can change in resource id igw--xxxxxxxx.

Comment: The `igw` part will remain as part of the identifier for all internet gateways, Amazon resource IDs follow a pattern of being prefixed with a short string of character used to identify the type of resource i.e. `i` for instance, `sg` for security group, `igw` for internet gateway :)

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)